# Timer created with DispatchSource.makeTimerSource() not firing up

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

In the following code, I attempt to create an infinitely repeating timer:

```
import Foundation
import Dispatch

class RepeatingTimer {

    var timer: DispatchSourceTimer?
    let queue: DispatchQueue

    var eventHandler: (() -> Void)?

    private enum State {
        case none
        case suspended
        case resumed
    }

    private var state: State = .none

    init() {
        queue = DispatchQueue(label: "serial.queue.1")

        timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: queue)
        timer?.cancel()

        timer?.schedule(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1), repeating: .seconds(1), leeway: .milliseconds(100))

        suspend()

        timer?.setEventHandler { [weak self] in
            print(Date())
        }

        resume()
    }

    deinit {
        timer?.setEventHandler {}
        timer?.cancel()

        resume()
        eventHandler = nil
    }

    func resume() {
        if state == .resumed {
            return
        }
        state = .resumed
        timer?.resume()
    }

    func suspend() {
        if state == .suspended {
            return
        }
        state = .suspended
        timer?.suspend()
    }

}
```

The timer is instantiated from the app delegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.rt = RepeatingTimer()
    return true
}
```

But then the print statement never gets invoked. I spent a fair amount of time trying to debug the code and I am not sure what I need to change for the code to function properly.

Answer (score 2):

In `init()` method comment the following lines:

```
// timer?.cancel()
// suspend()
```

Use `activate` instead of `resume` when possible:

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    timer?.activate()
} else {
    timer?.resume()
}
```

Comment: Did this fix the problem?

Comment: @Alexander Yes, it works fine on my Mac. As for me this answer should be accepted.

Answer (score -1):

You don't try call it from Appdelegate. You should call in view controller because the your code not support run in background.

If you called in viewDidLoad and it's not working, let try call it in viewDidAppear.